# How can I prevent the default event of clicking a checkbox in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

My goal here is to control whether or not a checkbox can be checked or unchecked based on a number of variables. If I can't stop the default behavior of clicking the checkbox then I can't achieve that goal.

For starters, when my user clicks on a checkbox, I want to get what it's checked/unchecked status was prior to being clicked so that I can run some if statements. Here is the code I am using.

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "input", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
    alert("true");
  }
  else {
    alert("false");
  };

});
```

And here is the demo on codepen: http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/lAmzy

When I click on the unchecked input, the checkbox is checked and I get an alert that says checked = true. But this should be false as the checkbox was empty prior to me clicking on it. I clear the alert and the checkbox goes back to being empty. As I understand it, event.preventDefault(); should stop the checkbox from being checked at all. But that doesn't seem to be what is happening. What am I missing?

Following that, once I have the pre-click value, I want to check or uncheck the input based on some if statements. Do I need to use event.preventDefault(); on `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click` in order to do this? If so, is there an efficient way of covering all three?

Comment: I believe the mousedown event occurs before the checked property is set and the click event fires afterwards

Comment: Thanks @kevmc. I used that and it worked. However, mouseup and click still affect the checkbox afterwards. It seems I have prevent the default action of all three in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try a mousedown event instead of a click?

Comment: I thought it worked for a second. But I've come to realize that if my mouse stays hovered over the input when I mouseup, the checkbox will get checked even if I set it to false in my code. http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/Csckh

Comment: I added event.stopPropagation() into your code. Is this behaving how you want it to behave?

http://codepen.io/johnlonganecker/pen/beELJ

Comment: That didn't work either. My goal here is to stop the browser from checking or unchecking the box under all circumstances. I need to run some if statements to decide if the box can be checked/unchecked. And that doesn't work when the browser keeps getting involved.

Comment: This seems ugly to me, but should do the trick.

http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/Csckh

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kfCyJ)

You have to use `mousedown` event so it read the value of the checkbox without activating click. then you could just trigger the `click` of the element using `.trigger()`

```
$( "body" ).on( "mousedown", "input", function(event) {


  if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
    alert("true");
  }
  else {
    alert("false");
  };

  $(this).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use .val to store the value?

Comment: @EternalHour the OP knows that the `alert()` part of the code can be altered into getting the value of the element.

Comment: I thought it worked for a second. But I've come to realize that if my mouse stays hovered over the input when I mouseup, the checkbox will get checked even if I set it to false in my code. http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/Csckh

Comment: @jimmykup and why would you do that?

Comment: @Yaje Why would I leave my mouse over the input on mouseup? Or why would I set the checkbox to unchecked? Either way my goal here is to control whether or not the box can be checked or unchecked based on a number of variables. If I can't stop the default behavior of clicking the checkbox then I can't achieve that goal.

Comment: you should've stated your goal entirely on your question.

Comment: @Yaje I did not expect to run into a further complication when I drafted the question. That said, the question is still about preventing the default behavior of clicking on a checkbox. And the mousedown() solution isn't enough apparently.